# Update FB app API version

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to update API version of my FB application from v2.0 to newer one, v2.6 or so.

[image]

But I can't find any *"button to upgrade"* API version in settings of application. Is there any option in settings or which way this can be done?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: What is shown there is only the _minimum_ API version your app can use - you can’t change that. What API version your app uses, depends on what version it specifies in the Graph API URLs it calls.